# Redirecting Backoffice login page to hac login page

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I’m following the SAP Commerce 123 Interactive tutorial. I'm using SAP hybris 19.05.
After adding the platformbackoffice extension and executing:

ant build

ant initialize

hybrisserver.bat start

I tried to open the backoffice with this following https://localhost:9002/backoffice. The page will be redirected to https://localhost:9002/login.jsp of hac.

Can anyone help me on this?

My localextensions.xml looks like:

```
<!-- Hybris123SnippetStart localextensions.xml_withbackoffice -->
<hybrisconfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="resources/schemas/extensions.xsd">
    <extensions>
        <path dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}" autoload="false"/>
        <extension name="concerttours"/>
        <extension name="platformbackoffice"/> 
        <!-- ext-template -->
        <extension name="yempty" />
        <extension name="yhacext" />
    </extensions>
</hybrisconfig>
<!-- Hybris123SnippetEnd -->
```

Comment: what is "ant build"? Is that "ant clean all"?

Comment: @geffchang: with ant clean all the compiled files will be first deleted then rebuilt again. 
But ant build doesn’t delete any compiled file. It rebuilds only files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I retried with the version 19.05.**13**, it works. The backoffice login page is displayed properly. This issue is related to 19.05.**14** version.